Azure Function - Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo does not log anything?
I am trying to add enrichers to my serilog in an Azure Function (running on .NET 8), but it is not logging anything with HttpContext?
I tested with a custom enricher and injected a HttpContextAccessor to it - turned out in the logging context the HttpContext is null.
What am I missing?
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); 
    
    var sinkOptions = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
     {
         TableName = "Logs",
         AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
         BatchPostingLimit = 10
     };

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithRequestHeader("X-Platform", "XPlatform")
        .Enrich.WithRequestHeader("X-App-Version")
        .Enrich.WithClientIp()
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
            connectionString: xxx
            columnOptions: new ColumnOptions(),
            sinkOptions: sinkOptions,
            restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Warning
        )
        .CreateLogger();
    builder.Services.AddLogging(lb =>
    {
        lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true);
    });


Please share your configuration file.

Its all configured in code.

If I enrich with a simple property that works just fine. But all the http context enrichment like headers and client ip is not working.

The enrichers using HttpContext will not work when using dotnet-isolated mode.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
